# Get data from Firebase Database with Specific node after successfull Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have used `FirebaseAuth` for Login purpose in application. While `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` I am creating the same user in `FirebaseDatabase` with some additional fields.The structre is

```
[{
   "email":"abc@gmail.com",
   "password":"xyz",
   "name":"sachin",
   "address":"Pune",
   "contact":"1234567890"
},
{
   "email":"pqr@gmail.com",
   "password":"def",
   "name":"Ashay",
   "address":"Pune",
   "contact":"1234577777"
}]
```

Suppose after successfull Login of user Sachin with email `abc@gmail.com` and password `xyz` I want the `address` and `contact` from database.How to get that values ?

Comment: post your node structure.

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation?

Comment: Yes. but i didn't find how to get data from database for specific node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference if you want to get a certain information from DB using UID

//To get logged in user information

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

var uid = user.uid; //get the UID from the current user

Answer (score 1):

According to me, you should use firebase **uid** as index for storing data. When user authenticated you will get user's **uid**, on this basis you can access user's data. I hope it will work.

Comment: can you tell me how to get that uid and then use it to get data from database ?

Comment: After login call this method FirebaseApp.getInstance().getUid(), you will get uid.